# In Dominion, how do Duration cards interact with King's Court / Throne Room?

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity, dominion-seaside

For example, suppose I play a King's Court on a Lighthouse. Do I get +$3 now and +$3 next turn? +$3 now and +$1 next turn?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**You get $3 now, and next turn as well.**

The [Seaside rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_326_gameRules.pdf) contain this blurb on page 4 that clarifies most such situations:

> If you play or modify a Duration card with another card, that other card also stays in your play area until it is no longer doing
>   anything. For example if you play Throne Room on Merchant
>   Ship, both cards stay in play until the Clean-up phase of your next
>   turn. The Throne Room stays in play to remind you that you are
>   getting the effect of Merchant Ship twice on that next turn.

There are some individual exceptions for some of the more unusual effects. Throne Room can't overcome Outpost's `This can’t cause you to take more
than two consecutive turns` clause, and you can't Throne Room a Tactician:

> Because you must discard at
>   least one card in order to gain the bonuses from Tactician, it is
>   not possible to Throne Room a Tactician to get + 10 cards, +2
>   Buys, and + 2 Actions.

So, bottom line, *most* Duration effects are simply doubled, but any time a combination with Throne Room starts getting confusing, it's best to check the rulebook - these situations are usually explicitly addressed.

Comment: To be clear, you *can* Throne Room a Tactician, it just won't do any good the second time the Tactician is played.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Pat Ludwig is correct, this is just additional clarifications of the rules regarding the tracking of actions:

Donald X writes:

> If you TR or KC a duration card, leave out the TR or KC with the duration card. [It's tracking that you doubled or tripled that card]
>
> If you TR or KC a TR-or-KC used on a single duration card (and up to 2 non-duration cards), don't leave it out. [It's not tracking anything.] [You still leave out the one that hit the duration card though.]
>
> If you TR or KC a TR-or-KC used on two or three duration cards, leave it out. [It's tracking the extra doubling/tripling done by the latter TR or KC, which also stays out.]
>
> Therefore I am going to go back on my ruling from yesterday for what happens if you KC a KC a KC used on 3 duration cards. The 3rd KC stays out obv. The 2nd one stays out; it's indicating that the 3rd one hits 3 things. The first KC is doing nothing and so goes.
>
> If instead you KC a KC, and that one KC's 1) a KC for 3 duration cards, 2) a duration card, 3) a non-duration, then you would keep the first KC out, as now it's indicating that the 2nd KC got to hit 3 cards, necessary for that 4th duration card to be tripled.

Slightly complicated, but the whole thread leading up to this can be found here at [BoardGameGeek.com](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/456393/throne-room-duration-cards/).  TR = Throne Room, KC = King´s Court.

Comment: Note that this answer is out of date. Donald has changed his mind on this, the current rule is that a TR/KC only stays out if it directly played a Duration. So TR+TR+Duration+Duration results in only 1 TR staying out with the Durations, not both.

Comment: What Gendolkari says seems to be the way the official dominion.games client has implemented it. For example when you do `KC(KC(a[Dur],b,c), d[Dur], e)`, both KCs stay out because they both directly touched the duration cards `a` and `d`. However if you instead did `KC(KC(a[Dur],d[Dur],c),b,e)`, only one KC will stay out: the one which directly touched `a` and `d`. (Especially relevant for cards like *Hireling*.)